# "Property is read-only" error when using select element inside ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ngmodel

I have an array of objects called `timingOfApptReminders` and am displaying them with `ngFor`. The array looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    daysUntilAppt: 1, 
    hoursUntilAppt: 0,
    minutesUntilAppt: 0,
  },
  {
    daysUntilAppt: 0, 
    hoursUntilAppt: 1,
    minutesUntilAppt: 0,
  },
]
```

My `ngFor` loop displays a row for each of those objects, and there is a `<mat-select>` element for each of the properties inside the object.

The `ngFor` displays each object correctly, however, if I click on one of the `mat-select` elements and make a change, I get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: ""daysUntilAppt" is read-only"

Here is my code:

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of timingOfApptReminders; index as i; let last = last">

    <!-- Days -->
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Days</mat-label>
      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="item.daysUntilAppt" name="daysUntilAppt-{{i}}">
        <mat-option 
          *ngFor="let day of days" 
          [value]="day"
        >
          {{day}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <!-- Hours -->
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Hours</mat-label>
      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="item.hoursUntilAppt" name="hoursUntilAppt-{{i}}">
        <mat-option 
          *ngFor="let hour of hours" 
          [value]="hour"
        >
          {{hour}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <!-- Minutes -->
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Minutes</mat-label>
      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="item.minutesUntilAppt" name="minutesUntilAppt-{{i}}">
        <mat-option 
          *ngFor="let minute of minutes" 
          [value]="minute"
        >
          {{minute}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

I suspect it has something to do with the way I'm doing `[(ngModel)]`, but I'm not quite sure how to do it the right way so that I'm changing the value of the correct property within the correct object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please share your TS code as well

Comment: @Brett I have not found any problems with the code. can you please share your code to http://stackblitz.com/.